# In the Bleach manga, does Byakuya really die in Bleach 502?

Tags: bleach

In the Bleach manga-volume 57, chapter 502, page 56-you see

> Byakuya on a wall with blood splattered everywhere, and a man with white hair (sorry for me not knowing his name; I have yet to actually read the manga, besides the first three volumes) says, "It seems Byakuya Kuchiki is dead."

My question is: is Byakuya *really* dead, here, or does he come back and whatnot? This scene *looks* as though he is, but we've seen desperate situations-like this-in the past chapters (or episodes) of Bleach where the character isn't **truly** dead; they come back later making a dramatic entrance, looking even more badass than before. See what I mean?

This ***CAN'T*** be the end for Byakuya Kuchiki. It just can't!

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for?  I can provide anything from a "Yes/No" to a fully detailed bunch of spoilers.

Comment: Hmm... you could answer with a "yes/no". Hahaha. I'm not looking for anything complicated; this is just something my sister and I wanted to know ASAP. And I'm sure anybody else who wants the answer doesn't want anything complicated, but put enough so that the people here don't delete your answer. -_- Go ahead and make it a spoiler. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably just live with the dramatic tension as you keep reading through the series.  That being said...

The short answer:

> He gets better.

The slightly longer answer:

> He gets better.  And gets a power-up.

The longer, more detailed answer:

> He hangs on by a thread.  And then Squad Zero--recall we heard about them during the Turn Back The Pendulum arc--shows up when the Quincies leave.  One of them takes Byakuya and a few others with them up to the Royal Palace.  Byakuya and a few others then get healed up, equipped, and trained in the Royal Palace.

I left a fair amount of details out of the above, so some things won't be spoiled, but it still spoils a fair amount even in its vague brevity.

Answer (score 2):

Kuchiki Byakuya didn't die here.

> He was saved by the zero division.

And he shows up in chapter 655.

> [image]

Comment: Does that mean he doesn't show up UNTIL then.

Comment: No, he shows up before that too. That chapter is just an example proof that he is still alive.

Comment: Do you know which chapter he first appears in, again??